# Spawn several different prefabs each one in one different position with Unity Mapbox SDK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapbox

I'm working in a Unity game with Mapbox SDK. I have this script to spawn in the map only one prefab in multiple positions. How can I do to spawn several different prefabs each one in one different position?

```
public class SpawnOnMap : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    AbstractMap _map;

    [SerializeField]
    [Geocode]
    string[] _locationStrings;
    Vector2d[] _locations;

    [SerializeField]
    float _spawnScale = 100f;

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject _markerPrefab;

    List<GameObject> _spawnedObjects;

    void Start()
    {
        _locations = new Vector2d[_locationStrings.Length];
        _spawnedObjects = new List<GameObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _locationStrings.Length; i++)
        {
            var locationString = _locationStrings[i];
            _locations[i] = Conversions.StringToLatLon(locationString);
            var instance = Instantiate(_markerPrefab);
            instance.transform.localPosition = _map.GeoToWorldPosition(_locations[i], true);
            instance.transform.localScale = new Vector3(_spawnScale, _spawnScale, _spawnScale);
            _spawnedObjects.Add(instance);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        int count = _spawnedObjects.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var spawnedObject = _spawnedObjects[i];
            var location = _locations[i];
            spawnedObject.transform.localPosition = _map.GeoToWorldPosition(location, true);
            spawnedObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(_spawnScale, _spawnScale, _spawnScale);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a GameObject Array, get different index every single time and spawn that object with the index you put.

Comment: Do you want to spawn different objects wihtout any input ? (OR)  you try to spawning objects with mouse position or click etc. which one is your issue ?

Comment: @UgurTufekci I want to spawn when the game starts, but a list of several prefabs in a list of positions, assigning one position to each object in order

Comment: I will share my projects part. I hope it will help you @Angelsm

Answer (score 1):

I use struct for coordinates:

```
public struct Point
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The x position
        /// </summary>
        public int X { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The y position
        /// </summary>
        public int Y { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the values of the struct
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">initial x</param>
        /// <param name="y">initial y</param>
        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
}
```

Then I used this struct from another class,
blueSpawn and redSpawn are different points and 
you can use different prefab for them like that:

another class:

```
 private Point blueSpawn, redSpawn;
            //this the method for your question
             private void SpawnPortals()
                {
                    //Spawns the blue portal
                    blueSpawn = new Point(0, 0);
                    Instantiate(bluePortalPrefab, Tiles[BlueSpawn].GetComponent<TileScript>().WorldPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                    //GameObject tmp = (GameObject)Instantiate(bluePortalPrefab, Tiles[BlueSpawn].GetComponent<TileScript>().WorldPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                   //You can save like a "tmp" if you need. 

                    //Spawns the red portal
                    redSpawn = new Point(11, 6);
                    Instantiate(redPortalPrefab, Tiles[redSpawn].GetComponent<TileScript>().WorldPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                }
```

TileScript and Portal are another classes but you can ignore them. By the way You can call this method in Start()